# Remove element from array if given in argument

Tags: javascript, arrays

I'm trying to get a hang of JavaScript (again) and so far it's not going great.

The challenge:

> You will be provided with an initial array (the first argument in the destroyer function), followed by one or more arguments. Remove all elements from the initial array that are of the same value as these arguments.

Why doesn't the code below remove the required elements for the second test case?

```
function destroyer(arr) {
  console.log(arguments);

  for (var array_i = 0; array_i < arr.length; array_i++){
    for (var arg_i = 1; arg_i < arguments.length; arg_i++){
      console.log("indexes", array_i, arg_i);
      if (arr[array_i] === arguments[arg_i]){
        console.log(arr[array_i], arguments[arg_i], "destroyed");
        arr.splice(array_i, 1);
        console.log(arr, arguments);
        array_i = 0;
        arg_i = 1;
      }
    }
  }
  return arr;
}
```

It successfully works here:

```
destroyer([3, 5, 1, 2, 2], 2, 3, 5);
```

But not here:

```
destroyer([2, 3, 2, 3], 2, 3);
```

Comment: You reset `array_i` and `arg_i` when you delete something, but you reset them to the initial values before the `for` loop increment. Thus, you'll sometimes skip an element. Try resetting `array_i` to `-1` and `arg_i` to `0`.

Comment: 'console.log(arguments);'  where is the variable `arguments` coming from?

Comment: @BenGlasser - [From here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/arguments)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're trying to compensate for the elements deleted along the way by resetting your indices. It's *much* simpler (and actually works) if you delete from the *end* of the array. No resets needed.

```js
function destroyer(arr) {

  for (var array_i = arr.length - 1; array_i >= 0; array_i--){
    for (var arg_i = 1; arg_i < arguments.length; arg_i++){
      if (arr[array_i] === arguments[arg_i]){
        arr.splice(array_i, 1);
        break;
      }
    }
  }
  return arr;
}

console.log( destroyer([2, 3, 4, 2, 3], 2, 3)  );   // [4]
console.log( destroyer([2, 3, 2, 3], 2, 3)  );      // []
```

Comment: Marvellous, I didn't think of that. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you modify the array while you're looping.

You can use filter function to do the same:

```js
function destroyer(arr) {
  var args = [].slice.call(arguments);
  return arr.filter(function(item) {
    return args.indexOf(item) == -1;
  });
}
document.getElementById('output').innerHTML = 
  JSON.stringify(destroyer([2,3,2,3], 2, 3)) + "\n" +
  
  JSON.stringify(destroyer([1,2,3,4,2,3], 2, 3))
```

```html
<pre id="output"></pre>
```

Comment: I knew my approach was wrong, this is probably the best way of solving it.

Comment: Whether it matters or not, but this method creates a new array of items rather than modifying the original. I mention this because `Remove all elements from the initial array`

Comment: @Xotic750 Good catch. In this case it doesn't matter much, but it's not indeed making a new array. It would be interesting to see which answer is the most efficient one, but that's for another time and another question.

Answer (score 1):

An alternative to reverse iteration using ES5 methods, and modifying the original array.

```js
function destroyer(arr) {
  var rest = Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments, 1);
  rest.forEach(function(unwanted) {
    var index = arr.indexOf(unwanted);
    while (index > -1) {
      arr.splice(index, 1);
      index = arr.indexOf(unwanted);
    }
  });
  return arr;
}

var initial1 = [2, 3, 2, 3];
destroyer(initial1, 2, 3);
document.getElementById('out1').textContent = JSON.stringify(initial1);
console.log(initial1);

var initial2 = [3, 5, 1, 2, 2];
destroyer(initial2, 2, 3, 5);
document.getElementById('out2').textContent = JSON.stringify(initial2);
console.log(initial2);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/es5-shim/4.4.1/es5-shim.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/json3/3.3.2/json3.min.js"></script>
<pre id="out1"></pre>
<pre id="out2"></pre>
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem here is you are relying on length to loop through the element of array and simultaneously you are rearranging the elements of the array.
So what happens is after removing the 2 and 3, 2 again comes at 0th place and your counter is ahead now and will never cover the position 0th. So there will be other case too in which you will not get the desired result.

So instead of this try looping through each argument only once,
Select an argument and then search for it in the array.

```
for(var i = 1; i < arguments.length; i++)
{
    var index = arr.indexOf(arguments[i]);
    while(index > -1)
    {
        arr.splice(index, 1);
        index = arr.indexOf(arguments[i]);
    }
}
```

And you will get what you want.